# Windows 7 cannot format new partition for itself

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, ntfs, format

I am currently running a dual boot with Mac OSX and Ubuntu.  I have four main partitions right now and about 200GB of free space.  One partition is an EFI partition for rEFIt, one partition is HFS+ Journaled for Mac, one is ext4 for Ubuntu, and the other is the swap for ubuntu.

When I run the Windows 7 installer, I cannot create a new partition or format the free space and I am given an error, "Too many partitions of that type on this disk", when I try to use the free space.  Any advice from other triple booters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to create an extended partition--you can only have four extended partitions per primary partition.  I haven't used the Win7 installer--can you direct it to create a primary partition in free space?  If not, you can certainly do so from Ubuntu. J ust create an NTFS partition, then start the Win7 installer--let Windows format the partition.

If that does not work, edit your question to show the output of "fdisk -l /dev/devicename" from Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you have primary and extended swapped. Reading the OP's question, it sound's like he has 4 primary partitions, and can't add a 5th. (Because you can only have 4 primary partitions.)

Comment: You're probably right. OK, you're surely right.

Comment: I figured it out on my own but thanks for the advice.  You were right, I could only have four partitions, which was why I could not create a partition for windows 7.  What I did was I removed the swap partition because with 2GB and after running Ubuntu for a year now, I know I will never need it.  I've got my system set with rEFIt efi partition, a Mac partition, a Windows partition that stores all of the data in NTFS format, and a Ubuntu partition.  By means of NTFS-3G running on my Mac Partition, I can now read/write data to the windows partition from any operating system.  Thanks again!